# Crystal repot open link in new browser tab

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report 2013 , I create a PDF file which has links the below solutions didn't work fo rme

{link}+'&sWindow=New' (It doesn't open in new tab)

```
   <a href="MYLINK" target = "_blank">Open</a>
```

If I do this in the PDF the link doesn't work , I can't clcik on it

Are there anyotehr solutions to try?

**My Requirement :**

I want to have links in my PDF report which if clicked will open in a new browser tab , currently the link opens itself in the same window and user will have to press the browser back button to see teh report again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a report that will be exported to pdf, and then you need the link works in that pdf, you can do this. Create a formula like below

```
@link ---> place inside your description

"your description"
```

Place it on your report. Then go to insert hyperlink(make sure that your formula is selected) icon and select on Hyperlink tab the option that says `A website on the Internet`and paste the link address  where says `Website Address` and the same thing if you need more than one.

Comment: Yes I have a report that is exported to PDF ,will your solution open the link in a new tab? I can already add a link and it works using the standard wizard in crystal report. But that link if clicked opens itself in the same window. I want it to be opened in a seprate window.

Comment: I tested yesterday and opened a new tab once you click on the link